# Is кучу времени a fixed phrase?

Tags: склонение

I came across the sentence: Мы и так ждали кучу времени

Why is it кучу instead of куча?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "куча" of something is a close equivalent of the English "heaps of" something. It's quite informal and can be used in similar contexts, meaning "a lot of", "a large amount".

> Куча денег -> Heaps of money

In your sentence, `куча` is the object of `ждали` and needs to be in the correct case. Most commonly, this is the accusative, which is why you have "кучу":

> Ждали (кого? что?) кучу

(The word can also take the genitive with a slightly different meaning, but not for this phrase. Also note that `времени` is, in turn, the object of `куча` and is in the genitive (from nom. `время`)).

Comment: It now makes sense when I think of it as the object of `ждали`

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not a fixed phrase. "Куча" can be used with any noun with the meaning "a lot".

У него куча денег. = He has a lot of money

У нас куча проблем. = We have a lot of problems

Лететь с кучей пересадок = fly with a lot of transfers

Since "куча" is a noun, it is declined accordingly, becoming "кучу" in the accusative case, "кучей" in the instrumental, etc.